# Finding the MODE in Excel with VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question about finding the MODE in excel. The table below shows 4 different income brackets and then how many families are in each bracket

I wanted to ask if its possible to find the MODE of the data set bellow without having to write it down like i did on the right side of the table?

I tried using MAX to find the largest number of families in a single income bracket and then using VLOOKUP to find the corresponding value in the other column, but for some reason it does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula instead

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(B23:B26),CHOOSE({1,2},B23:B26,A23:A26),2,0)
```

Actually, one of the `vlookup()`'s limitation is to read the array from left to right only.  In your problem, you have lookup values on the right side and values to return on the left.  `CHOOSE` function here does the job for reversing the data/array for you.

GOOD LUCK